# R creating a user defined function which calls an R scipt during its creation

Tags: r

I have found a nice piece of useful R code on github which with a few tweaks I can run as a user-defined function

the conventional way I have approached this is to download the code file (e.g. "nice_code.R") and then embed it into the body of a user defined function, called for example "myfunction". I then save the file as for example "Myfunction.R" and then I use "source()" to load  this file, where-after I then run myfunction().

However, I was thinking a better workflow might be to embed within my code creating "myfunction" a call to the github code - using devtools' "source_url()".

the big advantages of this is that if the original file on github gets updated, then myfunction gets updated as well.

so i was thinking along the line of having code something like this

```
myfunction <- function(x, y) {
              source_url("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R)
            }
```

However, this does not work - as instead of inserting all the github code, myfunction literally just has the source_url command inside itself.

Is it just not possible in R to embed a source like command within the function() function?

Or is it that I am leaving out a key option with source_url() and/or need to add other lines of code?

Thanks

Comment: I don't get what you want to achieve. Why do you put the `source_url` call in a function instead of calling it directly as you did with `source`? Generally speaking, you can of course use "source like commands" in functions, but this is different from copying the contents of the file in your function. Copying would also not be meaningful: Imagine there are two or more functions defined in the sourced file, how should your function behave in this case?

Comment: Hi AEF. It is because the original R script in github is not a function - and I need to add some other lines of code. 

Thus I can't load it directly using source_url.

Maybe I should have phrased the question better as: how do I access remotely an R script file (with a URL) and then embed the content it into a function.

Thanks

Comment: just download the source file with `download.file` or other function and save it in a string `s`, then `eval(parse(text=s))` in your function body.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have some code on Github:

```
cat(readLines(url("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/weihuangwong/d3eadd7a20a0111fc395dd21a4955bb4/raw/e250e039bd52184922ab26c4aecf3d8eac373951/lm_example.R")),
  sep = "\n")
# fit <- lm(as.formula(f), d)
# summary(fit)
```

OP wishes to create a function `myfunction` that includes the code above.  One approach would be to read the code from an external source as a character vector, embellish as required, output all the code to a temporary file, then `source` that file. E.g.

```
make_function <- function(temp) {
  ext_url <- "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/weihuangwong/d3eadd7a20a0111fc395dd21a4955bb4/raw/e250e039bd52184922ab26c4aecf3d8eac373951/lm_example.R"
  ext_code <- readLines(url(ext_url))
  code <- c("myfunction <- function(f, d) {",
            "cat('*** Summary of linear regression model *** \\n')",
            ext_code,
            "}")
  cat(code, sep ="\n", file = temp)
}
```

Then

```
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".R")
make_function(temp)
source(temp)
```

Now we have a function `myfunction` in the global environment:

```
ls()
# [1] "make_function" "myfunction"    "temp"         
myfunction
# function(f, d) {
# cat('*** Summary of linear regression model *** \n')
# fit <- lm(as.formula(f), d)
# summary(fit)
# }
```

Test the function:

```
myfunction("mpg ~ wt", mtcars)
# *** Summary of linear regression model *** 

# Call:
# lm(formula = as.formula(f), data = d)

# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -4.5432 -2.3647 -0.1252  1.4096  6.8727 

# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  37.2851     1.8776  19.858  < 2e-16 ***
# wt           -5.3445     0.5591  -9.559 1.29e-10 ***
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

# Residual standard error: 3.046 on 30 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7528,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.7446 
# F-statistic: 91.38 on 1 and 30 DF,  p-value: 1.294e-10
```

Answer (score 0):

With this function I created you can directly convert files to functions and supply the needed parameters (also with default values if you want):

```
makeFunctionFromFile <- function(file, ...) {
    content <- parse(url(file))

    formals <- as.list(eval(substitute(expression(...))))
    names_cand <- as.character(formals)
    only_name <- which(names(formals) == "")
    formals[only_name] <- rep(alist(,)[1], length(only_name))
    names(formals)[only_name] <- names_cand[only_name]

    res <- function(){}
    body(res) <- as.call(c(as.name("{"), content))
    formals(res) <- formals
    environment(res) <- parent.frame()
    res
}
```

Call with:

```
myfunction <- makeFunctionFromFile("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R", x, y)
```

You can specify the arguments in any way you like, all of these work:

```
myfunction <- makeFunctionFromFile("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R")
myfunction <- makeFunctionFromFile("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R", x=, y=)
myfunction <- makeFunctionFromFile("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R", x=1, y)
myfunction <- makeFunctionFromFile("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R", x, y=)
myfunction <- makeFunctionFromFile("https://github.com/........./nice_code.R", x, y=2)
```